# Search without submit button with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, opencart

I need to add class to the input element in Opencart search(in **header.tpl**)

**HTML CODE:**

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="input-search" class=""/>
```

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#input-search").keyup(function (e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $("#input-search").addClass("button-search");  
   }
  });
 });    
</script>
```

I am using Opencart and to redirect to the search page you have to have the class **.button-search**. I don't want to have a submit button.
When I add some text to the input and then when I press Enter the script should add class to the input and redirect to the Opencart search page.

Comment: I don't think by just adding the class to the input element will submit the form. You need to submit it with js.

Comment: @Jai in Opencart you can't have a form in search.  Yes, I have js file(common.js) and there is defined the .button-search

Comment: `window.location.href = "../yoursearchpageurl" + $(this).serialize();`  this would do for you then. change the url like this "../yoursearchpageurl" this will be your search page url.

Comment: @viktorR would you post your search page url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you want buddy.

code: http://jsfiddle.net/webcarvers/xdt7g/1/
preview: http://jsfiddle.net/webcarvers/xdt7g/1/embedded/result/

HTML

JS

```
$("#inputSearch").on('keypress',function (e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $("#inputSearch").addClass("buttonSearch");
       $("p").text("Class added = " + $("#inputSearch").attr("class"));
       window.location.replace("http://www.yahoo.com/")
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When the button is inside a form you can submit it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#input-search").keyup(function (e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $("#input-search").addClass("button-search");  
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
   }
  });
 });    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#input-search").keyup(function (e) {
   var kc = e.keyCode || e.which;
   if (kc == 13) {
      $(this).addClass("button-search");// get the current context with 'this'
      window.location.href = "../yoursearchpageurl?" + $(this).serialize();
   }
  });
 });    
</script>
```

---

As you mentioned that you don't have a form in your page so when you add the class to your button then just after that you can change your page url as suggested with `$(this).serialize()`

Comment: @dreamweiver OP does not have a form in his page so submit button is not needed. _as OP commented in his post's comment_

Comment: Well what do you know, you just edited the answer now , which leaves my comment out of scope, so deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation method like below:

```
$('body').on('keyup','#input-search', function (e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $(this).addClass("button-search");  
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is redirect to a page with the value from the `input` you can do the following `window.location.href = "?search=" + this.value;`

Your code will be like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#input-search").keyup(function (e) {
   var kc = e.keyCode || e.which;
   if (kc == 13) {
    $("#input-search").addClass("button-search");
    window.location.href = "?search=" + this.value;
   }
  });
 });    
</script>
```